# Looking for a way to take sql query results then bind matching ID's from results to an array "bindGrid"

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

So I'm primarily working with C# and have a method which runs a query that will return x amount of results based on the situation and then set these results as an array "dataGrid". Atm I need a means of creating a method or something which can go through these results in dataGrid then and looking for matching "taskID's" in the taskID columns then take those results and put them into another array called "bindedGrid".

Any ideas? I hope I worded this properly.
I'm working with Visual Studio btw and these SQL query results are coming from an API which we have set up. So the method calls another method in the API which then returns the proper results from the SQL server.

Comment: The situation you sketched is unclear. Are you talking about one and the same table or are there two tables, for example `DataGrid` and `Tasks`?

Comment: The results are pulled from 2 different tables but the results are ultimately set to the array dataGrid. I just need a method which can go through these results and filter out results which have a matching "taskID" column. Then take those findings, and set them to another array called "bindID".

Comment: Hopefully that clears it up a bit

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use a `foreach` loop. Take a look at the official documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

```
foreach(var item in dataGrid){

   //imagine you have 10 "variables" in your array, the "item" will be 
   the first, then loop and will be the second, etc...and the loop goes
   trought all your "variables". here you need to implement your logic, 
   using the "item" namespace and you will be working with one of those
   "variables" at time.

}
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to this. Would you be able to provide an example if possible?

Comment: Lets just say that you received 5 results from a query that is now set to a variable "dataGrid". One of the columns for the results would be the "taskID" column.
How would you use the "foreach" loop to go through those results in dataGrid and select only those results which have matching taskID's?

Comment: @TommbirNoor I've edited my answer. I recomend you to learn the foreach loop, there are tons of videos on YT about this.

Answer (score 0):

With what should `taskID` match?

Is the array an array of `DataRow` objects?
If so, there are three ways of doing this, `Lambda`, `foreach` or `LINQ`

**Lambda**

```
var matchings = dataGrid.Where(dr => dr["taskID"].toString() == "matchkey");
```

**foreach**

```
List<DataRow> matchings = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (var dr in dataGrid) {
    if (dr["taskID"].toString() === "matchkey")
        matchings.add(dr);
}
```

If you want to join another table, I prefer to use LINQ:

```
var matchings = from row in dataGrid
         join task in Tasks
         on row["taskID"].toString() equals Task["ID"]
         select row;
```

Tell me if this is not what you need.

You might need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file for this to work.